# RDS SPLA Licensing issue in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: amazon-rds, remote-access, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop

I tried out the method given by Microsoft, as [Install RDS client access licenses on the Remote Desktop license server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-install-cals)

But there were some issues.

1. When I enable RDS feature,  it automatically enables a **Built-in open
   licence** which has unlimited RDS sessions with **120 trial dates**.
2. Once I apply SPLA licence with **3 RDS sessions** ,then  it shows both, 
   built in license and new SPLA licence.
3. But currently active licence is **Built-in open license** and I were
   unable to remove this **Built-in open licence**. (because there is no
   option to remove built-in one)
4. There for, though I apply SPLA license with 3 sessions, it is not
   the active one. Still I have unlimited RDS session with 120 trial
   dates.

What is the correct method of applying RDS licence ?

[image: Screenshot of RD License Manager]